# Transistor and relay

Tags: transistors, relay

I am working my way through the Make: Electronics second edition, and I have a bit of a problem with experiment 18. I made my circuit like in the picture below (sorry for low quality; also, please ignore green arrows).

[image]

Then I changed the position of the S2 switch. After that I would expect to have 9V on the emitter of the T1 transistor, but instead I am having 4,5V which is not enough to activate the relay. Moreover, when I disconnect the emitter from the relay, I am getting 9V on the emitter.

I don’t understand why the circuit works like this. I have checked the transistor and the relay in separate circuits to see if they are broken, but I couldn't find anything wrong with them.

Can someone please suggest what might be wrong here and how else I could troubleshoot this?

Comment: What other measurements have you made? For example, does the supply voltage also drop? Are you by any chance trying to power the circuit from a 9V battery and the 9V relay coil takes just too much current for the battery to provide it?

Comment: I didn't make any other measurements except ones that I mentioned. What else I might measure? I am using universal power supply with adjustable voltage output (from 3V to 12V) that has maximum of 150 mA of stabilized direct current.

Comment: @gryz The LED at the top of the schematic doesn't make sense to me. That fact also leaves me a little bit worried about the rest.  The BJT is being used as an emitter follower with a 10 k Ohm base resistor. There will be a voltage drop across it based upon the relay current requirements (which we don't know.) [Here is](https://www.jameco.com/z/AL-D9W-K-Fujitsu-2-Pole-2-Form-C-DPDT-Small-PC-Mount-Latching-Relay-2A-9V_2077386.html) a 45 Ohm, 9 V relay, for example. If yours is similar, then I'm not at all surprised with your measurements. And your power supply is then perhaps too feeble, too.

Comment: @gryz I can't say for sure, as I've never read the 2nd edition (or any edition) of what you are working through, right now. But I'm beginning to feel as though it may not be the better product for you. You may want to find something else that is written better and more accurately.

Comment: 150mA for the power supply sounds too weak, I would prefer a 1A of output.  The schematic also does not mention what kind of relay this is? different relays draw different currents on the control part (the coil side), and yours maybe drawing too much current, which might be limited by your transistor. Also, have you tested that your relay works as you think it does? (it shorts the pins you think it does) Lastly, I havent analyzed the circuit, but if you think it can be a mistake on the schematic, you can maybe test it on LTspice.

Comment: Well these measurements are not enough to make any comclusions what the problem is, so feel free to make more measurements and try to see where the voltage drops too much. Which relay part number that is, are all transistors and diodes connected in correct orientation, have you double checked which pinout the transistor has (there's 6 possible combinations), etc?

Comment: Relay that I am using is [here](https://www.jameco.com/z/G5V-2-H1-DC9-Omron-General-Purpose-9V-Relay-DPDT-2-Form-C-Through-Hole_2260068.html) I guess I have to use more powerful power supply to make this circuit work… 
@jonk I am novice when it comes to electronics and this book supposed to be for the beginners, but it is true that I had to look up stuff in other sources to make some of the projects form this book work (on more than one occasion), so maybe you are right that I should try something else.

Comment: @gryz Yes. 16.7 Ohm is very low and requires a LOT of current. Your power supply seems very much inadequate. I'm not comfortable with the circuit, either. Especially with that particular relay, which appears to require quite a lot of current. The transistor will require a fairly large amount of base current as a result and this will cause quite a large voltage drop across a 10 k Ohm resistor. So I think you have some problems to resolve. I'll add +1 for your question, given your sincere interactions here. Thanks for that. :)

Comment: Thank you all for your help :)

Comment: Please [edit] the relevant information (relay part number, measurements, etc.) into the post rather than including it only in the comments.